# Migrate EJB + WAR to Jboss EAP6

Tags: jboss, ejb, jndi, jboss-eap-6

I have a .jar with EJBs and a .war that invokes these EJBs.

They used to be deployed in a Jboss SOA Platform 5 and now must be in a Jboss EAP 6.

The .war is looking up the EJBs with `ejbname/remote`. This is hardcoded (I checked with a decomplier).

I know that, in EAP 6, the EJBs are registered in the JNDI like `[/<application-name>]/<module-name>/<bean-name>[!<full-qualified-interface-name>]`.

Is there any way for me to change the JNDI registry name of the EJBs. Maybe via Jboss CLI?

I only have the binaries and have no access to the source.